# curl connection timeout on php while working on command line

Tags: php, curl

I have a php api which I hosted in another server / domain, and accessing using php curl from a different server, suddenly it stopped connecting but when I try accessing the api in command line  it will work.

```
<?php 
$requestPayload  = array(
        'user_id' => API_USER_ID,
        'user_key' => API_KEY, 
        'select_limit' => '*',
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://example.com/direct/_api/list.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($requestPayload));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

The above code will give me error `Http error Failed to connect to example.com port 443: Connection timed out`, but when I run url in command it works fine

```
curl -XPOST -d 'user_id=vvcZ....&user_key=T0Z8...&select_limit=*' 'http://example.com/direct/_api/list.php'
```

Please I don't know if the problem is from the sending server or the api server.

Comment: In the cURL command, you try to access to "http://", not "https://". Works with https ?

Comment: @Syscall command works in both http and https, in php https will show error port 443 while http wll show 80

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the line which you are defining the connection timeout:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
```

You also added a lot of rules in your cURL, like `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`. Try to remove these rules. I notice that in the command-line curl the url hasn't https, which will not work on your code because of your rule.

Comment: I did remove the timeout and other options but yet